# Failed to subscribe to notification characteristic in bluetooth low energy

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my UWP application, I want to connect to a Bluetooth low energy peripheral device and subscribe to its notification characteristic.
this is the application `Connect` method:

```
private async Task Connect(string id)
{
    var device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(id);
    var gattService = (await device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(Guid.Parse("00002600-005d-0012-00ef-00000000717f"))).Services.FirstOrDefault();
    if (gattService != null)
    {
        var notificationCharacteristic = (await gattService.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(Guid.Parse("00009e76-0c4d-0db6-08b6-000000020445"))).Characteristics.FirstOrDefault();
        if (notificationCharacteristic.CharacteristicProperties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await notificationCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to write to the notification characteristic, the `WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync` method raise an exception:

> The attribute cannot be written. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80650003)

I test this scenario using android application and I can write notification characteristic without any problem.
I want to know what the problem in UWP?

**Update:**
I change the UUID of notification characteristic descriptor from the peripheral device and see that the problem was solved.

Comment: Have you  written another notification characteristic successfully such as battery service?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I update my post, the problem is solved

Comment: Anyway, the `WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync` should not throw Exception, it should just return proper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, after some test I change the UUID of notification characteristic descriptor from the peripheral device and see that the problem was solved.